# How to handle a Client/Server application for sending message and/or files

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, serversocket

I have done a lot of searches around here, but I haven't found anything that matches even a bit of what I need.

I'm not so expert in client/server application, and this is my first attempt, so, please, be patient if I have made some error or if I made silly questions.

Now, back to my problem..

I need to build a multi-client / server application.

The server side should be a simple manager for the clients.

So, for example:

- the server can change some clients parameters
- accepts files from the clients
- other boring stuff.. that basically can be translated in sending string or sending files or getting string and files

The clients, in the other hand, is a complex application (at least, for the user) that should send to the server:

- some user registration data (no need for security stuff here, I'm already pretty messed up with a simple client/server connection)
- a PSD file that should be the result of the user work, so when the user click "I'm done" the application get this PSD file and send it to the Server for storing purpose
- other client information such us the default configuration data, and so on..

So, my question is basically this:
How can I handle the communication from the server with one specific client?
I mean, I have the server up, and I what to change a configuration just for one client.

I suppose I need to store the clients in some way.. like in an array (a `List`), but I don't know if this is the right way to do  this.
(Basically I dont't know how the classes `Socket` and `ServerSocket` works.. if this can help you to better understand)

Also, when the server is up and listen.. the GUI need to be updated to show the new connected clients, so I need some kind of listener to the server that fires an action back to the interface when a new Client shows up?
(A lot of people uses the
    while(true) {
        socket = server.accept();
    }
method, but this doesn't sound very smart to me..)

This is the basic Client.java and Server.java files that contains the client and server basic functions that I wrote based on a lots of Google searches.

But all of the code below doesn't math all my needs..

## Client.java

```java
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Client extends Socket {

    private static Client    instance    = null;

    /**
     * The main init() function for this class, to create a Singleton instance for the Client
     * 
     * @param host
     *            The host of the Server
     * @param port
     *            The port of the Server
     * @return The Client instance that is a new instance if no one exists previusly,
     *         otherwise an older instance is returned
     * @throws UnknownHostException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Client init( String host, Integer port ) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        if ( Client.instance == null )
            Client.instance = new Client( host, port );
        return Client.instance;
    }

    /**
     * Default Constructor made private so this class can only be instantiated by the
     * singleton init() function.
     * 
     * @param host
     *            The host of the server
     * @param port
     *            The port of the server
     * @throws UnknownHostException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private Client( String host, Integer port ) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        super( host, port );
    }

    /**
     * Function used to send a file to the server.
     * When this function fires, the Client class start sending a file to the server.
     * Internally this function handles the filesize, and some other file information
     * that the server needs to store the file in the correct location
     * 
     * @param filename
     *            The filename of the file that will be sended to the server
     */
    public void sendFile( String filename ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        // The file object from the filename
        File file = new File( filename );

        // A string object to build an half of the message that will be sent to the exceptions
        StringBuilder exception_message = new StringBuilder();
        exception_message.append( "The File [" ).append( filename ).append( "] " );

        // Check if the file exists
        if ( !file.exists() )
            throw new FileNotFoundException( exception_message + "does not exists." );

        // Check if the file size is not empty
        if ( file.length() <= 0 )
            throw new IOException( exception_message + "has zero size." );

        // Save the filesize
        Long file_size = file.length();

        // Check if the filesize is something reasonable
        if ( file_size > Integer.MAX_VALUE )
            throw new IOException( exception_message + "is too big to be sent." );

        byte[] bytes = new byte[file_size.intValue()];

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( file );
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream( fis );
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream( this.getOutputStream() );

        int count;

        // Loop used to send the file in bytes group
        while ( ( count = bis.read( bytes ) ) > 0 )
        {
            bos.write( bytes, 0, count );
        }

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        fis.close();
        bis.close();
    }

    /**
     * Function used to send string message from client to the server
     * 
     * @param message
     *            The string message the server should get
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void sendMessage( String message ) throws IOException
    {
        OutputStream os = this.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter( os );
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( osw );

        bw.write( message );
        bw.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Function used to get a message from the Server
     * 
     * @return The message the server sent back
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String getMessage() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream is = this.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( is );
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( isr );

        String message = br.readLine();

        return message;
    }
}
```

## Server.java

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server extends ServerSocket {

    private static Server    instance    = null;
    private Socket            socket        = null;

    /**
     * 
     * @param port
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Server init( Integer port ) throws IOException
    {
        if ( Server.instance == null )
            Server.instance = new Server( port );
        return Server.instance;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param port
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private Server( Integer port ) throws IOException
    {
        super( port );

        // Maybe this is something that needs to be improved
        while ( true )
            this.socket = this.accept();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param message
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void sendMessage( String message ) throws IOException
    {
        OutputStream os = this.socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter( os );
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( osw );

        bw.write( message );

        bw.flush();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String getMessage() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream is = this.socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( is );
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( isr );

        String message = br.readLine();

        return message;
    }
}
```

aehm.. apologize for my english.. please.

Comment: The easiest way to handle multiple clients on your server is to use a thread for each connection

Comment: @Cruncher I have seen something like that somewhere, and basically what I need to do is a new Runnable Socket class for the server side, that store the `server.accept()` socket, right? But even if I do something like that, how can I handle the communication between the server and a specific client?

Comment: @Crunchier: Not necessarily the easiest. One of the easiest. Event-loops in a single-thread could work fine as well. Multi-Process could work fine as well. They all are simpler in some aspects and harder in others.

Comment: @haylem well in my experience anyway, threading was easiest, but definately not the most scalable, depending on the longevity of connections.

Comment: @AndreaRastelli The run method will be looping for each client, which would be a different instance of that class. In that class you store information about who that client is. Whenever you get a message in that instance, you have all of the information that you need.

Comment: @Cruncher So, as I was thinking, I need some sort of `List` that stores all this Thread objects, witch one of those has a run() method that continuously ask the related client for "something".. right?

Comment: @haylem how about the Event-Loops stuff you was talking about? Can you explain it more deeply or link some useful webpages here, please?

Comment: @AndreaRastelli storing a list of the connections is only necessary if the clients need to communicate with eachother somehow, like a chat client. If their relationship is only with the server (like a web server) then it's not really necessary, the instance can hold the socket information.

Comment: @AndreaRastelli: here would be an example of the concept from the Tornado Python server: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html . It's a rather simple thing. In fact, if you've **never** done client-server before, I'd think that's the approach you should start with, and then move on to other ones. It's rather simple, the server listens for incoming connections, and then dispatch to handler functions. As mentioned it's less intuitive in some areas than a MT-ed approach (for instance, for managing client data connections), but it's simple.

Comment: @AndreaRastelli: It's not a concept limited to client-server **network** code though. It's a common concept in GUI frameworks as well, where you'd usually what's often called a Big Event Loop. Sometimes that BEL might be in a separate thread though (e.g. the EventDispatchThread in Java Swing). It's pretty much a continuation of the `while (true) { accept(); /*...*/ }` method you mention. And lately it's gotten more pull again with the growing use of server-side JavaScript, in particular because of Node.JS. Whether that's a good idea... well, that depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @Cruncher mmh.. So if, for some reason, the connection with one client goes down, and the client need to reconnect to the server.. I have the same client instantiated two times.. or I miss something?
What I was thinking was something line a `Map<String, ClientThread>`. So, if I need to get some client information, I can always access to it by the key of the Map, and if the connection goes down.. I simply need to overwrite the same Key in the Map, right?

Comment: @AndreaRastelli Well, after the connection dies then the thread should stop. If you want to save any information from the last connection the next time they connect, then a map would be perfect. You really need to make sure that whatever string you're using to map is unique. Also, if this application uses sensitive information, that imposes a security risk. If I knew someone elses unique String, I may be able to trick you into giving me their session.

Comment: @AndreaRastelli A follow up, if you need this information to be stored persistantly, then you may need a database as well.

Comment: @AndreaRastelli: a good program idea to implement to get started with client-server programming is a simple IRC client/server or FTP client/server program. That can be helpful as you already have existing implementations to test and compare against, and you can focus on a single side of the problem at a time if you wish to.

Comment: @Cruncher well.. the database is a good idea, but the time I have to complete this application is limited (and I should finish everything for the 16th of this month, and the client/server stuff is just **one** of the things that I need to complete).
For the security stuff.. as I mentioned, actually I'm pretty messed up with all this client/server things.

Comment: @haylem well.. the IRC is a good idea to start with, but the time I have to complete this project ends the 16th of this month.

Comment: @AndreaRastelli Sounds like you need a team

Comment: @Cruncher sounds like I need a new job. Believe me.

Comment: @AndreaRastelli: 11 days sounds doable: you seem proactive in your research! Not sure what the entire project is about but that seems acceptable if the interface doesn't need to be too fancy and you can postpone extra features to later service releases. However, you might want to keep your supervisors/stakeholders posted about the evolution of the thing if the deadline is about to woosh by.

Comment: @AndreaRastelli: Also, at first I took your question more as a personal endeavor, so I didn't recommend this, but you might want to look at some framework to alleviate most of the pain and not worry too much about the perfect case (except if you have requirements you didn't tell us about, like scalability needs, etc...). May I suggest you have a look at something like [netty.io](http://netty.io/) (to stay on the event-driven side of the programming models)?

Comment: If you just want the clients to send strings, or files to the server then maybe you should take a look at restful webservices. The reference implementation is jersey http://jersey.java.net/

Comment: @haylem in Italy (in general) and in the company I'm working for (in particular), the programmers are a professional figure that looks like something annoying and that is needed just to be competitive on the market. If, tomorrow, the way to be competitive will become "wear a pink ribbon" then the unemployment rate could raise level never seen before..

Comment: @mike may be right in that implementing this on top of a web server using REST services would also remove most of the trouble for you. But I assume there might be requirements we're not aware of, or that you originally wanted the more barebones approach (and maybe you don't have the web development experience? If you do, that could be faster for you).

Comment: @haylem Well.. I have absolutely no knowledge in java related to the web (or the net, or whatever is called). In java I only know how to do graphics stuff (i'm a mathmatician with a degree in applied mathematics to the graphics, and I used java a lot, and processing also, to make visual things using OpenGL), but for this kind of task I'm absolutely a newbie. This is my (forced) first attempt in build something like this client/server "thing".

Comment: Rest is not that complicated. If noone else does I'll create a rest example for you. But I'm in a hurry right now. ...if you use jersey together with grizzly webserver you have a 100% java solution.

Comment: @mike thanks, but I think that I will give a try to the netty.io framework that haylem suggested.. if I will spend more than a couple of hours in configuration and other stuff with that I will give a try to the REST you suggested.. thanks anyway, all of you have helped me a lot!

Comment: @AndreaRastelli: go through the examples on this page, especially the first ones under "Fundamental" and "text protocols" for the basics. Then pick the ones that suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Your question made me curious, how a modern java approach would look like. I also had some problems as I started experimenting with sockets, so here a little example that should help you out.

The server handles each client in its own 'thread', you could say that's the basic client/server architecture. But I used the new `Callable<V>` instead of threads.

I did not extend `Socket` nor `ServerSocket`. I nerver saw that before. I think it's better in that case to favor composition over inheritance. It gives you more control, since you can delegate what and how you prefer.

For more information I recommend you to take a look at the [oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ClientServerExample
{
  private final static int PORT = 1337;
  private final static String LOOPBACK = "127.0.0.1";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    ExecutorService se = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    se.submit(new Server(PORT, 5));

    ExecutorService ce = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    for (String name : Arrays.asList("Anton", "John", "Lisa", "Ben", "Sam", "Anne"))
      ce.submit(new Client(name, LOOPBACK, PORT));

    ce.shutdown(); while (!ce.isTerminated()) {/* wait */}
    se.shutdown();
  }
}

class Client implements Callable<Void>
{
  private final String name;
  private final String ip;
  private final int port;

  public Client(String name, String ip, int port)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.ip = ip;
    this.port = port;
  }

  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception
  {
    Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    out.println("Hi, I'm " + name + "!");
    out.close();
    s.close();
    return null;
  }
}

class Server implements Callable<Void>
{
  private final int port;
  private final int clients;
  private final ExecutorService e;

  public Server(int port, int clients)
  {
    this.port = port;
    this.clients = clients;
    this.e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(clients);
  }

  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception
  {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
    int client = 0;
    while (client < clients)
    {
      e.submit(new ClientHandler(client++, ss.accept()));
    }
    ss.close();
    e.shutdown(); while (!e.isTerminated()) {/* wait */}
    return null;
  }
}

class ClientHandler implements Callable<Void>
{

  private int client;
  private Socket s;

  public ClientHandler(int client, Socket s)
  {
    this.client = client;
    this.s = s;
  }

  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception
  {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    String fromClient;
    while ((fromClient = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
      System.out.println("FROM CLIENT#" + client + ": " + fromClient);
    }
    in.close();
    s.close();
    return null;
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> FROM CLIENT#0: Hi, I'm John!
>   FROM CLIENT#2: Hi, I'm Sam!
>   FROM CLIENT#1: Hi, I'm Ben!
>   FROM CLIENT#3: Hi, I'm Anne!
>   FROM CLIENT#4: Hi, I'm Anton!

Answer (score 1):

*this is till work in progress, bear with me... Was originally just addressing what I already posted in comments regarding the possible models. updates coming up later tonight.*

## Different Models

Generally what comes to mind are these 3 approaches:

- Multi-Process Model
- Multi-Threaded Model
- Event Loop Model

These aren't limited to the client-server model for network
programming though, and it's fairly common to see them show up in
other scenarios, like in GUI programming.

#### Multi-Process Model

// incoming

#### Multi-Threaded Model

// incoming

#### The Event Loop Model

An [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) is a construct where a program waits for incoming
instructions to dispatch messages to other parts of a system. Its main
advantage lies in the simplicity of its implementation and in its
lightweight aspect.

It's especially useful if your main program is not to perform any
computationally intensive and long actions, so as not to block the
next incoming connection for too long. The idea is simply to wait, get
a connection, dispatch to a separate sub-system for something to do,
and wait for an answer until you can respond.

You can either wait for the sub-system's answer before you respond
(synchronous), or start dealing with other connections until the
sub-system returns and you can respond (asynchronous).

---

## Update

Based on your latest comments, it would appear to me that you are under some strict time constraints and that maybe you should postpone the learning experience a bit and privilege speed of development. For this reason, I'd recommend you consider using a framework that would allow you to cover your bases and take care of the cruft for you - I originally thought you were asking this as part of a personal endeavor and were attempting to learn. I'd re-prioritise that and focus on getting the thing done, even if comprehension might suffer at first.

So... based on what we discussed, I'd recommend you turn towards **[netty.io](http://www.netty.io/)** an event-driven network programming framework (see the [wiki](http://netty.io/wiki/) for examples).

Comment: Please, keep updating this answer, this stuff is something I need to learn for future updating and upgrading for this application, so the more I know the better I will improve in the future.